# facebox[] not working within links displayed by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebox

I've several links that require the use of facebox to display information but it wont just work with ajax. It works fine displaying information via php or javascript but within ajax, it just wont work.

I think somewhere within ajax callback function, it's stripping off this:

```
rel=facebox[]
```

And without that within the links, facebox cannot work.

**Here's the sample ajax code that just wont work:**

```
function dataRecHandler(){

    if(getData.readyState == 4){
        if(getData.status == 200){

    var getUserId = 3;
    var myPix = 'userpix_58513892_92.jpg';

            var data_div = document.getElementById('data_div');
            data_div.innerHTML =  '<a href="view.php?getUserId=' + getUserId + '" rel="facebox[]"><img src="user_img/' + myPix + '" width="30" height="30" /></a>';         

        }
    }   

}
```

**Here's a similar test with javascript that works perfectly:**

```
var getUserId = 3;
var myPix = 'userpix_58513892_92.jpg';

        var data_div = document.getElementById('data_div');
        data_div.innerHTML =  '<a href="view.php?getUserId=' + getUserId + '" rel="facebox[]"><img src="user_pic/'+myPix+'" width="30" height="30" /></a>';

</script>
```

Just in case it's needed, here is the facebox codes within the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'facebox/src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'facebox/src/closelabel.png'
      })
    })
  </script>
```

Does anyone have an idea or clue on how to fix this?